# Magnetic field saturation in ac circuit

Tags: ac, inductor, saturation

We have an AC voltage source connected to an ideal inductor that has no resistance.The inductor is wound around a ferromagnetic material.  The maximum value of the driving voltage source is big enough that it will drive the core into saturation during the first positive half cycle.

Will the induced emf be zero over the interval of saturation, and what will be the value of current over such an interval?

I think that the induced emf should be zero over the interval of saturation because the change in the B-field will be zero and consequently the time derivative of magnetic flux is zero.  But that leads me to a contradiction because the driving voltage is not zero during saturation then, how will the voltage across the inductor be zero ?

Comment: Look at the Steinmetz model, when not in saturation the magnetizing branch has a high inductive reactance. When it goes into saturation, it has a low inductive reactance, not zero.

Comment: You have "*an ideal inductor that has no resistance*"! Wow! What's it made of and where did you buy it?

Comment: @user207332 Read [Feynman Lecture Series, Volume II, Chapter 36](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_36.html) to gain the basics. Then re-ask your question in light of what's there. (Your question will change, once you understand that chapter.)

Comment: I already got the answer after i asked the question..there will be an induced emf because after reaching saturation the permeability will drop as if there was air and the B-field will keep changing no matter we reached saturation or not

Comment: V=LdI/dt +  I*DCR . As L drops I rises at some rate. If static then it is only resistive.

Comment: @user207332: There is no such thing as a model transformer but they *do* write about them in books as it simplifies the theory. There is nothing in your question to say that this is a model. You said, "We have ...". An edit, perhaps ...

Answer (score 2):

As inductance falls due to the saturation of the core, with a voltage source supplying the stimulus, the rate of change of current increases proportionately. Given that Faraday’s law of induction is: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

The induced voltage remains largely the same. This of course assumes that the voltage supply is capable of delivering the high current needed during core saturation.

This is quite commonly observed in transformers when the core is saturating quite badly; the secondary output waveform still looks nicely sinusoidal despite the current input to the primary being quite nasty looking.

Here is a good picture that is quite revealing. It shows a sine wave voltage across an inductor, the distorted current waveform and the magnetic flux as a result of core saturation: -

[image]

So, despite the core saturation, a decent sine wave shape is seen in the flux. Picture from [here](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/AC/AC_9.html).

Comment: Thank you man that was very helpful

Comment: @user207332 I don't know if you are aware of the finishing off process to questions that are deemed satisfactorily answered. I mention this because you've asked 8 questions now and none have had formal acceptance of any answers. Of course, this depends on you but, if you have got answers that satisfy the question these should be formally accepted. For those questions that have currently not received a satisfactory answer then please leave comments for further clarification. You also have acquired the reputation to deliver upvotes for answers that are of interest.

Comment: Thanks.some people here like showing off , like that guy called transistor.he knows that i am assuming pure inductive coil for simplification and instead of helping , he made fun of me in the comments.it is not easy to find helpfu peoplel here and that is why i use this site as my second choice after quora.although you write a very very short question on quora , you get lots of explanations without complainig about trivial things that are understood implicitly.